# Spring Boot - Scheduler configuration

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, spring-scheduled

In Spring Boot application I have several scheduled tasks. I want them to run simultaneously, so in my configuration I should create `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` object and register it in `ScheduledTaskRegistrar`.
 I find two ways to do that:

**way 1**

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class SchedulerConfig implements SchedulingConfigurer {

    private final int POOL_SIZE = 10;

    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar scheduledTaskRegistrar) {

        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler scheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();

        scheduler.setPoolSize(POOL_SIZE);
        scheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("name");
        scheduler.initialize();

        scheduledTaskRegistrar.setTaskScheduler(scheduler);
    }
}
```

**way 2**

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class SchedulerConfig implements SchedulingConfigurer {

    private final int POOL_SIZE = 10;

    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar scheduledTaskRegistrar) {

        scheduledTaskRegistrar.setTaskScheduler(this.poolScheduler());
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskScheduler poolScheduler() {

        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler scheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();

        scheduler.setPoolSize(POOL_SIZE);
        scheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("name");

        return scheduler;
    }
}
```

1. Which way is better or they do exactly the same?
2. Why in way 2 initialize method of ThreadPoolTaskScheduler object isn't called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Second way is better because you **let Spring handle class** `TaskScheduler` and later you can use it in other classes using  `@Autowired` as:

```
@Autowired
TaskScheduler taskScheduler
```

Answer (score 3):

Why in way 2 initialize method of ThreadPoolTaskScheduler object isn't called?

Because now, ThreadPoolTaskScheduler is a bean and it follows the Bean Life Cycle.

You can see that ThreadPoolTaskScheduler implements InitializingBean.
So after spring builds this bean, it will call the afterPropertiesSet() method .

If you inspect the code of ThreadPoolTaskScheduler, you will see:

```
public void afterPropertiesSet() {
    this.initialize();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also tempted to define such a configuration. Since Spring Boot 2.1.0 you can do this via configuration (`org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.task.TaskSchedulingProperties`), both the number of threads and threadNamePrefix can be customised.